# Asynchronous read in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, disk

How do I read a portion of a file using `pread(2)` in C? I've tried using the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on `open()` but the read still seems to block the thread (i.e reading a large portion at once, 1GB, seems to hang the thread for about 300ms on my M1 mac)

I've looked into `aio_read()` but that does not seem to work at all on some systems and seems to either spawn a new thread to run the callback, or run all callbacks on one thread, which is not suitable for my needs.

Ideally I'd like a solution in which the process does not have to do any waiting and can simply poll to check if the buffer has been populated, something analogous to how nodejs would implement `fs.read(fd, ..., callback)`

What is the proper way to achieve what I'm looking for? I've searched online for hours but most questions seem to concern sockets / pipes and not actual files (where `read()` literally waits for new data to arrive)

Context: server software with high CPU loads and very high disk usage (multiple million reads per minute of about 1KB-4KB each), the vast majority of reads will be made to an NVMe drive (with average 0.01ms response time, but expected to be much higher under load)

The current accepted solution seems to be using thread pools, any information on the overhead of frequent thread switching would also be useful

Comment: It might be interesting to time how long a 1GB `memcpy()` takes on the same Mac; the 300 milliseconds might simply be the amount of time it takes to move the loaded data from the kernel to your buffer.  If so, then the way to avoid the delay would be to read smaller amounts of data at a time.

Comment: As for the meat of your question, you could always spawn a separate thread that is dedicated to doing blocking reads, and whenever it reads some data, it adds that data to the end of a synchronized FIFO (or whatever) and then signals your main thread to go pick that data up ASAP.  Polling every millisecond is usually a bad idea, since threads that burn up CPU cycles that way tend to get punished for it by the system's scheduler, by being deprioritized.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner memcpy does seem to take about 300ms too. I'm still confused as to how the data is immediately available, does that mean disk read is faster than memcpy() and therefore no waiting is required? How would I wait non-blockingly in a situation where the bottleneck is the disk and not memcpy?

Comment: The data might have been pre-cached in RAM (either via a clever pre-fetch algorithm, or as a side effect of the last time that same file was read from disk).  MacOS (like most modern OS's) is quite clever about quietly using whatever "free" RAM is available to cache recently loaded blocks of filesystem data, just in case they might be useful again in the near future.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yeah, that thought occured to me right before reading your comment, it seems to pre-cache the file (the read is about 200ms slower the first time then faster after that). It seems the first time round it still waits synchronously those extra 200ms, which brings us back the the original question :/

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to wait non-blockingly for the availability of data from a file -- if it was a network socket, I would say you could block inside select(), but "real file" file descriptors don't support select() that way.  Hence my recommendation to spawn a separate thread to do the reading; since that thread would be dedicated to reading file data and nothing else, it wouldn't matter that that thread is blocked some of the time.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So there is no way to read asynchronously? Does libuv (nodejs) use a separate thread too?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it, but then again I haven't done very much looking, since for my codebase I just went with the "roll your own async-reads via a dedicated thread" approach and that sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner wouldn't a solution with a thread pool incur an excessive context switch overhead? If I want to make full use of a CPU with 8 cores (I would create 8 threads) and I want to make a `read()` on thread 7 let's say, that would use at least two context switches (one to switch to a new, 9th thread, that is able to make use of the CPU while the read is happening, and a second to switch back to thread 7 once the read has completed). Given disk reads can be quite fast (especially with NVMe), it seems that using a thread pool just moves the bottleneck from `read()` to context switches?

Comment: Edit: I didn't consider that context switching between threads of the same process is significantly cheaper than typical context switching between different processes, whoops

Comment: Dunno what the context-switch overhead would be; you'd have to measure it, but I've never noticed any performance problem with that in my own code.  In any case, I am confident that a properly implemented event-driven system would have much less overhead than anything that is based around waking up every 1mS to do a non-blocking poll; since the context switches would only occur when there is actual data to be handled (rather than twice per thread per millisecond)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner for my needs I'll need A LOT MORE than two reads per thread per millisecond. I'm taking making 40,000 reads in the space of under 50ms, that's why I'm making the effort to find the absolutely most efficient solution (including switching from nodejs to C)

Comment: Please, show some code.  What you have done is important to give you feedback.

Comment: You should read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and incorporate a complete program that can be run an tested for any error you can be having in your code.

Comment: Switching the question somewhat (which is why I'm making this a comment rather than an answer), have you investigated using mmap(2) to map a data file directly in to memory? That means that you can immediately thereafter act as if the contents were read in, and leave the actual IO to the virtual memory system in the kernel. That's what I'd do, with an input of that size.

Comment: @NormanGray I have but unfortunately a minimum read of 16K (page size) is far too high for my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out on one of the comments of this question the most accepted way to do this is synchronously with a thread pool, which is what I will be using.

Answer (score 2):

You say

> How do I read a portion of a file using pread(2) in C? I've tried using the O_NONBLOCK flag on open() but the read still seems to block the thread (i.e reading a large portion at once, 1GB, seems to hang the thread for about 300ms on my M1 mac)

Of course `O_NONBLOCK` is not an issue here.  The kernel doesn't block your process on open because it wants, but because it is necessary.  Using non blocking open will not make the read to go ahead, just because you said `O_NONBLOCK`. (what it means is that every system call you make that requires the descriptor to be open will fail with the error `EAGAIN` and you will not get your data written anywhere)

By the way, it's quite strange that your kernel will have a read ahead of 1Gb  from your file at once.  Your call will block always (the kernel will not give as much as it has, if you have asked for 1Gb, your process ---and the file inode will be locked--- will wait for the data to come from the disk until it has passed to your process the full Gb of data)  While this is not true for a socket, or a pipe, it is for a file.  The kernel implements file reading as an atomic operation, to deal with other threads/processes accessing the same file, and the file remains locked (and no other system call can proceed on that file, while the inode is locked)  If you had used `read` or `write` instead of `pread` or `pwrite` the result whould have been the same (the only implementation difference is that the file pointer is not used at all in the operation, as you provide it in the call)

Reading a 1Gb file from disk (because believe me, the file is stored in the disk) in only 300ms is a very good performance (it is an average of 3.5Gb/s, for probably a single/nonthreaded process)  this can be a result of having part of the data you want to read already buffered (so no disk access is in use)  Even if you have a disk capable of transferring 40.0Gb/s or more, think that the disk driver must spend some time in changing heads (if that is the case) or servicing other processes requests.  A second factor that can be slowing your data access is that, if you put your process into computing (or i/o) only task, the kernel soon will lower its priority to benefit shorter i/o processes, and this operation, while efficient for the more dynamic processes, just will affect negatively to yours.  Another issue is that using huge variables and a large amount of memory, makes your process more suitable to be swapped out, and this will require to reswapp it in to satisfy the partial reads as they are written to the variable you designed for storing the buffer.  This will slow also your program.

> Ideally I'd like a solution in which the process does not have to do any waiting and can simply poll every millisecond to check if the buffer has been populated, something analogous to how nodejs would implement fs.read(fd, ..., callback)

That's not the way to get things done efficiently.  Polling is a way of waiting for something to happen, but not efficiently, so your paragraph is a bit contradictory in itself.  Today's computers almost do no polling to resources, because the events that come (like a disk finishing the transfer) in play normally interrupt the CPU that distracts for a few us. to attend the disk device and store the data in place.  Only when things are finished, your process is awaken and left to go, instead of having it waiting in a loop and consuming expensive CPU time.  The best way to ask the kernel for something is to ask for it, and remain waiting (blocked, not consuming CPU cycles doing something absurd like polling if it is ready) the kernel to give you the whole thing when it is ready.

When you go to a burguer to get a meal, normally you are not asking the waiter each minute if your hamburger is ready.  You just sit, and wait for the waiter to come to your table with the hamburger ready to eat.  The reason is that you want to eat it warm, there's not a buffer of burgers waiting to be served in a pool for you to ask it.  The `O_NONLOCK` simply doesn't work here.  If you ask the system to return `EAGAIN` in a loop, until it answers differently, the hamburger will not be made faster.  The waiter will be pissed off (well, you have a very patient kernel) and you will finally be banned from that place.

If the case is that you want to be free to do something else, this is never the solution.  You have at your disposal other resources like the `select/poll` system calls, or using `O_NONBLOCK` to continue, until you don't have more to do, and then block in a no `O_NONBLOCK` call (that will wait for the meal to be ready)  It takes time to service you, and you must understand it, even if things happen so quick that you cannot wink an eye in that time.

BTW, reading how do you `pread` the data (I mean, reading your actual code) will probably show more facts on the problem.  You should read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and incorporate a complete program that can be run an tested for any error you can be having in your code.

Sometimes, the best way to read a full bunch of data is just the following code:

```
#define ONE_GIGABYTE (1024*1024*1024)
...
    static buffer[ONE_GB];
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c == fgetc(input)) != EOF && buffer_size < ONE_GB) {
        /* append your character to the buffer */
        buffer[buffer_size++] = c;
    }
    /* now you have a full Gb of file in your memory */
```

But, again, beware, as having 1Gb variables is probably a candidate for your process to be swapped out by the kernel, making it neccessary to reswap it in, when the data is being traspassed to user mode, making several swapin/out in your system, making things to run slower.

**Note:** I don't know the reasons why you are using `pread` instead of just `read`, but if you think that specifying the file pointer in the call will make things go faster, you are wrong: The reason of having a system call to specify the pointer is to avoid the kernel updating the file pointer and not disturbing other processes that are doing sequential reading sharing the pointer file.

Comment: I use `pread` because I'll need frequent and random access to distant parts of the file, only one process accesses the file, and it will be running at highest priority on dedicated server hardware. I'd like to be able to do useful work like processing incoming network packets while a read is waiting. In fact, an ideal workload would have multiple reads occuring at any one time (high amounts disk access will also mean drastically increased response time), and 25-75% CPU usage (across all available threads). That's why it's crucial that the CPU is never "waiting around" doing nothing :P

Comment: In short I'd rather spend 5% CPU time polling than 25% waiting on a few million read operations

Comment: where, in the question did you state that?  Do you want me to guess?  is that correct... if you are so expeienced, why are you asking here?  My apologies for giving you some hint.... continue reading 1Gb chunks, you are the correct way :)

Comment: BTW, how are you going to deal with swapping?  Have you considered running your process in a non multitasking environment? :)

Comment: Swapping? wdym?

Comment: In addition, 1GB read was a test. I don't intend on doing reads as large as 1GB in production (and if I do then reading character by character is possibly guaranteed to be the slowest way to go about it, in addition to not actually solving the problem at all)

Comment: Because assume other processes will be running there.

Comment: There will be, but this is a very small concern. Not much else happens on this machine, beyond routine kernel tasks or the occasional bash shell

Comment: Then you don't have a problem... you are so smart that know everything you tell me, everything I tell you... and everything you don't tell me. No problem... you need a faster computer.  Of course I don't know everything you don't tell me, so you are smarrter than me.  Sorry for answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect job for `mmap`.  You can use `mmap` to get a `char*` to the contents of the file directly.

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
...
{
    int fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) { /* handle error */ }

    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) { /* handle error */ }

    char* map = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) { /* handle error */ }
    
    /* Since you mentioned you are doing a lot of random access,
     * use this hint to tell the kernel how you plan to use it.
     */
    madvise(map, sb.st_size, MADV_RANDOM);

    /* Once, you have the map, you actually don't need the file
     * descriptor open anymore...
     */
    close(fd);
}
```

Make sure to store the `sb.st_size` somewhere, as that is now your reference to the end of the file.

The driver that handles the actual disk reads is going to be page fault interrupts.  Most of the data will remain in memory until the kernel needs some and swaps your data back out to disk.  The other awesome feature of `mmap` is how simple the code becomes once you have one.  You want byte 10000?

```
char byte_10000 = map[10000];
```

Want to search for a specific character or string? Just throw the whole map into `memchr` or `memmem`.  No reads, no system calls.  You sort of just make the whole thing the kernel's problem =]

Comment: mmap is not asynchronous

Comment: @BlobKat That is true, though I don't understand why you *need* async here.  Sounds like you are coming from a Javascript background or something where everything takes so long that such a model is needed. This isn't the case in C. `mmap` is going to be plenty fast for any situation I can think of.  After running for some time, much (if not all) of the file access will be in memory (file cache)... Can't get much faster than that.  Doing async for something in memory is going to add overhead, not remove it.  But if you *absolutely need* async, then you want `io_uring`.

Comment: I want the disk reads to be async not the cache access. When a page hasn't been cached it needs to be fetched which is definitely not fast enough if blocking

Comment: I just want to point out, that `pread` is going to have a near similar effect.  Once you read from the disk enough, it will be in the file cache.  `mmap` is just a nice way to accomplish the same thing while skipping over kernel when cached.  That is how modern systems work.  Adding threads to that is only slowing you down.


If you want fast access no matter what, then @luiscolarado's solution is by far the best.  Just read all the data into memory (1-time penalty).  Then, *everything* is guaranteed memory access.  No amount of threads will ever surpass this speed.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Linux (version > 5.1) you could try to use `io_uring` non blocking interface. Example of usage for disk file read operations could be found here https://github.com/shuveb/io_uring-by-example/blob/master/03_cat_liburing/main.c

Comment: awarding bounty because stackoverflow bounties expire apparently...